# Highcharts with JSON to customize multiple series

Tags: javascript, json, highcharts

I would like to add multiple series in my graph from a json file with 4 columns (date, open incident, closed incident and in progress incident).
I can show my graph with the number of incident open (http://jsfiddle.net/269us/) but I can't find the 3rd and 4th columns of JSON file.

Here is the structure of my JSON file:

```
[[1325462400000,3,12,14]
 [1325548800000,7,14,8]
 [1325635200000,10,11,24]
 [1325721600000,21,13,16]
 [1325808000000,13,15,9]
 [1325894400000,2,15,4]
 [1326067200000,10,13,15]]
```

I want to reach as a result of this type in order to customize each series (open, closed, in progress)

```
var date = []
   open = []
   close = []
   inprogress = []
   datalength = data.length;

for (i = 0; i <dataLength; i + +) {
    date.push ([
         data [i] [0]
    ]);

    open.push ([
         data [i] [1],
    ]);

    close.push ([
         data [i] [2],
    ]);

    inprogress.push ([
         data [i] [3],
    ]);

    }

    series: [{
       type: 'spline',
       name: 'open',
       data: open,
       dataGrouping {
              units: groupingUnits
       }
   } {
       type: 'column',
       name: 'close',
       data: close,
       dataGrouping {
              units: groupingUnits
       }

      .............
      .............

   }]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are trying to create 3 data arrays to use in 3 series (open, close and in-progress). Try something like this:

```
for (i = 0; i <dataLength; i + +) {
    var date = data[i][0];
    open.push ([
         date,
         data[i][1]
    ]);

    close.push ([
         data,data[i][2] //data instead of dat.
    ]);

    inprogress.push ([
         date,data[i][3]
    ]);
}
```

You sould now be able to use these 3 arrays as the data in your series:

```
series: [{
   type: 'spline',
   name: 'open',
   data: open,
   dataGrouping {
          units: groupingUnits
   }
},
{
   type: 'column',
   name: 'close',
   data: close,
   dataGrouping {
          units: groupingUnits
   }
},
{
   type: 'line',
   name: 'inprogress',
   data: inprogess,
   dataGrouping {
          units: groupingUnits
   }
}
```