# Highcharts JSON multiple series

Tags: json, highcharts, series

I've made a working graph in Highcharts with x values for timestamp and y values for other values. Now I'm trying to plot 3 more y values against the same x values. What is the easiest way to do this in Highcharts using JSON?

I've tried to follow this advise: [Highcharts with JSON to customize multiple series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15632751/highcharts-with-json-to-customize-multiple-series), but it won't work with a JSON array structured like this: [[1361574000000,121201,0,0],[1362006000000,122019,40.6,59.276],[1363388400000,...]]

Do I have to create a multidimensional JSON array?

Answer (score 1):

If you need three series, and those are your values, you need something like this:

[{
   data:[[1361574000000,121201],[1362006000000,122019]]
},{
   data:[[1361574000000,0],[1362006000000,40.6]]
},{
   data:[[1361574000000,0],[1362006000000,59.276]]
}]

Comment: Is this valid data?
[{"data":[[1361574000000,0],[1362006000000,40.6],[1363388400000,35.7],[1363820400000,41.24],[1364511600000,40.56],[1365112800000,38.96],[1365544800000,39.8],[1366063200000,40.58],[1366668000000,40.79],[1367272800000,38.06],[1368309600000,37.95],[1368655200000,41.31],[1369346400000,40.16]]},{"data":[[1361574000000,0],[1362006000000,1.46],[1363388400000,1.42],[1363820400000,1.42],[1364511600000,1.37],[1365112800000,1.41],[1365544800000,1.41],[1366063200000,1.35],[1366668000000,1.45],[1367272800000,1.36],[1368309600000,1.36],[1368655200000,1.36],[1369346400000,1.37]]}]

Comment: It would be, except you have some odd characters in there.  They don't show up when the code is pasted here. but look at the data when put into this fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/JVNjs/315/